# WPF Debugging AvalonEdit binding to Document property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, sharpdevelop, avalonedit

all day long I am sitting and trying to find out why binding to AvalonEdits Document property isn't working. AvalonEdit is an advanced WPF text editor - part of the SharpDevelop project.(it's going to be used in SharpDevelop v4 Mirador).

So when I set up a simple project - one TextEditor (that's the AvalonEdits real name in the library) and made a simple class that has one property - Document and it returns a dummy object with some static text the binding is working perfectly.

However in real life solution I'm binding a collection of SomeEditor objects to TabControl.
TabControl has DataTemplate for SomeEditor and there's the TextEditor object.

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tabControlFiles" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
 <TabControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:SomeEditor}">
   <a:TextEditor 
   Document="{Binding Path=Document, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NoopConverter}, IsAsync=True}" 
   x:Name="avalonEdit"></a:TextEditor> 
  </DataTemplate>  
 </TabControl.Resources>

 <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
   <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"></Setter>
  </Style>
 </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

This doesn't work. What I've investigated so far:

- DataContext of TextEditor is set to the proper instance of SomeEditor
- TextEditors Document property is set to some other instance than SomeEditor.Document property
- when I set breakpoint to no-op converter that is attached to that binding it shows me the correct value for Document (the converter is used!)
- I also dug through the VisualTree to obtain reference to TextEditor and called GetBindingExpression(TextEditor.DocumentProperty) and this did return nothing
- WPF produces the following information:

  System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Document; DataItem='SomeEditor' (HashCode=26280264); target element is 'TextEditor' (Name='avalonEdit'); target property is 'Document' (type 'TextDocument')
- SomeEditor instance that is bound to already has a created and cached copy of Document before the binding occurs. The getter is never called.

Anyone can tell me what might be wrong? Why BindingExpression isn't set ? Why property getter is never called?

//edit: new tests and new results

I've read some more and set the binding in code behind. When I do that it works.
How come setting this in XAML doesn't work and doing the same thing in code does?

//edit2: The code also fails when called immediately after adding the object to the observable collection that is used as higher level DataSource.(that's not long after the xaml binding should fire). That makes me think this is timing issue. Anyone can tell something about it ?

//edit3: The binding code:

```
private List<T> GetObjectOfTypeInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject dpob) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dpob);
    List<T> returnlist = new List<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dpob, i);
        T childAsT = child as T;
        if (childAsT != null)
        {
            returnlist.Add(childAsT);
        }
        List<T> lst = GetObjectOfTypeInVisualTree<T>(child);
        if (lst != null)
        {
            returnlist.AddRange(lst);
        }
    }
    if (returnlist.Count > 0)
    {
        return returnlist;
    }
    return null;
}

private void RebindMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (XHTMLStudioPrototypeFileEditor ed in CurrentProject.OpenedFiles)
    {

        List<ContentPresenter> cps = GetObjectOfTypeInVisualTree<ContentPresenter>(tabControlFiles);
        if (cps != null)
        {
            foreach (ContentPresenter cp in cps)
            {

                foreach (DataTemplate dt in tabControlFiles.Resources.Values)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object o = dt.FindName("avalonEdit", cp);
                        TextEditor ted = (TextEditor)o;

                        bool isDataBound = BindingOperations.IsDataBound(ted, TextEditor.DocumentProperty);
                        if (!isDataBound)
                        {
                            BindingOperations.SetBinding(ted, TextEditor.DocumentProperty, new Binding("Document"));
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(isDataBound);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you used to programmatically create the binding? Also, what happens if you remove the IsAsync?

Comment: Nothing happens if I remove IsAsync. I was trying every combination there is to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are six more things to try:

Search your carefully application for any place at all where you directly assign to the Document property of a TextEditor.  It looks like some code, somewhere is doing an `avalonEdit.Document = ...` which would overwrite the binding.  I would search your entire app for the match-case whole-word strings "Document" and "DocumentProperty" and give each occurence a moment's thought to see if it could be setting this property.

Set a breakpoint in TextEditor.OnDocumentChanged to see if the document is being properly bound and then changed back later.  Check call stacks with "Just My Code" disabled and showing external code.

Try setting breakpoints in the NoopConverter.Convert, SomeEditor.get_Document, and TextEditor.OnDocumentChanged to figure out the precise sequence of operations.  Also note when the Binding error message is shown.

Temporarily modify TextEditor's constructor to store a reference to every instance in a public static List field so you can determine which TextEditors have ever been created, then write code that looks through them displaying their `GetHashCode()` and their `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(editor, DocumentProperty)` results.  Make sure you take out the public static field when you're done!

Take the "Path=" out of your XAML that constructs the Binding so it will better match the C# version.  (I once had a problem where the XAML interpreted the path different than the Binding constructor because of the ITypeDescriptorContext passed to PropertyConverter.)  The exact equivalent to the C# code you posted is `Document="{Binding Document}"`.

Create a custom trace listener and set a breakpoint in it to get the call stack when the binding error is produced, search up the stack frames to find the objects involved and give them debugger object ids (right-click, Make Object ID), then investigate the actual values of properties to make sure they are as expected.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'll briefly answer the points. 1) Done, no results. 2) Done in the first place. 3) Different results each time- probably different threads doing binding and the rest. 4)&5) There is no problem with creating TextEditors. I've already checked that. I always get a new instance and I know the C# code was ok - it worked.

And now final results: after a few cleanups and builds it started working all of a sudden. I don't know what is the reason, but still my guess is thread safety and timing. I suppose not all of that code is thread safe and this was why it behaved so strange.

Comment: After few days I downloaded AvalonDock and that required rewriting it another way - now I have direct access to AvalonEdit instance and I can do whatever I want. It's working.

Thank you very much for your answer. It was very thorough and you presented valuable debugging techniques. The bounty's yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: I had the same problem and looked through the AvalonEdit source; it seems the problem is that the TextEditor constructor overwrites the Document property (instantiates a new TextDocument); if you comment this out, the bindings work; however, if you don't have a binding, you'd need to make further modifications. I'll try to discuss this with the authors and maybe suggest a patch.